# Detect MacBook notch in macOS Monterey and higher

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

This is a question for macOS, not iOS.

macOS Monterey on MacBook pro 2021 provides a notch for the first time, which hides parts of the menu when in full screen mode or maximized state. In order to apply a modified menu in that case, I'd like to to detect the notch programmatically.

How can I do this? Didn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

First, check whether you're running on macOS 12 or later, because the APIs are only available on macOS 12 or later. You can use `if #available(macOS 12, *)` to check.

Then, for the `NSScreen` of interest, check one of these properties. They should also give the same (yes/no) answer:

- Is [`safeAreaInsets.top`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/3882821-safeareainsets?changes=latest_major) non-zero?
- Is [`auxiliaryTopLeftArea`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/3882915-auxiliarytopleftarea?changes=latest_major) non-nil?
- Is [`auxiliaryTopRightArea`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/3882916-auxiliarytoprightarea?changes=latest_major) non-nil?

For example:

```
extension NSScreen {
    var hasTopNotchDesign: Bool {
        guard #available(macOS 12, *) else { return false }
        return safeAreaInsets.top != 0
    }
}
```

Comment: And what are you supposed to do if there's a notch? How do I know if the notch is covering one of my menus, and what do I do about it?

Comment: The OP says “In order to apply a modified menu in that case”. Maybe he's writing a game or other heavily custom full-screen app where he draws his own menu bar.

Comment: Regardless, it's a reasonable question. If Apple didn't want us to be able to design around the notch, they would not have provided the APIs to locate it.

Comment: Hey, go easy, I didn't downvote the question. I'm asking _you_ a reasonable question. I'm disturbed by the notch and I want to understand whether it will break my apps.

Comment: Thank you @rob. If I understand correctly these properties return the available rect left/right and with these Infos I can rearrange my (indeed custom) menu. Great! I will test this with the new MacBook pro once I receive it in early November and keep you updated.

Comment: And indeed it looks like this is going to be a serious issue: https://twitter.com/SnazzyQ/status/1453143510111059968